# BigQuery UPDATE multiple nested columns

Tags: nested, google-bigquery

I would like to understand the principle of how to update a BigQuery Nested table.

For example, with have a table:

```
ID   GROSS   OL.ID  OL.GROSS   PL.ID   PL.GROSS
1    100     12     200        34      454
             34     465        56      5667
             67     7876
```

And I would like to update the gross value for the main, OL. and PL. to any other value

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `OL` and `PL` are arrays in this example but it's hard to tell. You can use a query like this:

```sql
UPDATE dataset.table
SET
  OL = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ID + 2 AS ID, GROSS + 3 AS GROSS FROM UNNEST(OL)),
  PL = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT 1 AS ID, GROSS + 3 AS GROSS FROM UNNEST(PL))
```

See also the [`UPDATE repeated records` example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_examples) in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and extends Elliott's answer

Usually, there are more than just two elements in struct and you need to update just one or two - instead of explicitly calling them all out to rebuild original array - you can use below approach

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table` SET
  OL = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(1.1 * GROSS AS GROSS) FROM UNNEST(OL)),
  PL = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(1.2 * GROSS AS GROSS) FROM UNNEST(PL))
```